# The Intellij IDEA does not launch after editing the VM options file

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, jvm

In Intellij IDEA 2019 I mistakenly added incorrect lines to the VM option file (Menu | Help | Edit Custom VM Options). After that, the IDEA does not launch. Reinstallation didn't help. When I run IDEA from terminal, it gives the following error:

```
~/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-C/ch-0/193.7288.26/bin$ ./idea.sh

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated 
in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M,
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M, -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m
```

But at the same time, these lines are not in the idea64.vmoptions file:

```
~/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-C/ch-0/193.7288.26/bin$ cat idea64.vmoptions

-Xms128m
-Xmx750m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-XX:CICompilerCount=2
-Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off
-Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
-Dsun.java2d.renderer=sun.java2d.marlin.MarlinRenderingEngine
-Dsun.tools.attach.tmp.only=true
```

I don't understand what the error is. Can anyone help? Thanks for any comment/answer!

Comment: This is for Android Studio but it might share options with InteliJ https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html

Comment: Can you check home directory for the idea folder and there should be options file?

Comment: @Eugen Martynov Thanks you for the prompt and link! I will check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete/edit the [custom .vmoptions file](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869).

Usually it's located in the [IDE configuration directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#config-directory).

On Linux look for

`~/.config/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.2/idea64.vmoptions` (for 2020.2 Ultimate)
`~/.IntelliJIdea2019.3/config/idea64.vmoptions` (2019.3 Ultimate)
`~/.IdeaIC2019.3/config/idea64.vmoptions` (2019.3 Community)

Toolbox managed installations may use different location:

`~/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-C/ch-0/193.7288.26.vmoptions`

Comment: Thank You very much!!! It helped me! I deleted the ~/.IdeaIC2019.3/config/idea64.vmoptions file + reinstalling IDEA.